# Testing that file has been moved to "processed" for route ftp://host/incoming?move=processed in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the endpoint defined as `ftp://host/incoming?move=processed`. How would I make sure that the file has been moved to "processed" directory using camel test infrastructure? How would I interecept this? Is Camel creating a separate endpoint for "processed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no extra endpoint in that process. The file is moved using the FTP API.

You can test it either by consuming the file from the FTP server afterwards using the Camel API for that, for example with a consumer template. Something alike this:

```
Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receiveNoWait("ftp://host/incoming?fileName=processed/" + theNameOfTheFile);
assertNotNull(exchange);
```